# QueryDsl, elegant way to make method cascades NULL safe with Java or Groovy

Tags: methods, groovy, nullpointerexception, querydsl, cascading

If often run into NPEs when traversing cascading methods that could be null somewhere a long the path. For instance I'd like to query the customer's "salutation" property..

```
     ConstructorExpression giftCE = ConstructorExpression.create(Gift,
            order.a.b.c.salutation
    )
```

any or all of a,b or c could be be NULL resulting into a NPE.

What's the best "querydsl"-way to guard against such NPEs both in Java or Groovy?

(I'm not sure if Groovy's Elvis op covers this situation within a querydsl statement)

Answer (score 0):

You can use field accessors instead of the final fields. This way you won't run into NPEs http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.1.1/reference/html/ch03s04.html#d0e1713

I am not sure if you can use them in Groovy with field/property syntax, since they are not getters.

In your case it would become

```
ConstructorExpression giftCE = ConstructorExpression.create(Gift,
    order.a().b().c().salutation
)
```

Comment: I guess ConstructorExpression.create strictly rejects properties to be null. So even if I use Will Ps solution at one point or the other order.a.b.c.salutation could be null by itself which leads to java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.mysema.query.types.ConstructorExpression.create(ConstructorExpression.java:79)

Comment: Yes, null arguments are invalid, and in your case also not really wanted.